# How to make IE start withhome page by InternetExplorerDriver so they won't retained when the next test runs?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-driver

When I run tests using `InternetExplorerDriver` it sometimes retains tabs from the old tests when next tests are run.

I know this is connected to the setting in IE presented below, but I need that setting being automated through `InternetExplorerDriver`.
How to set IE to use `Start with home page`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not quitting the driver after completing the work.

You can use **driver.quit** whenever you want to end the program. It will close all opened browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session.

If you do not use **driver.quit** at the end of the program, the WebDriver session will not close properly and files would not be cleared from memory. This may result in memory leak errors.

Comment: I use driver.quit, but sometimes during debugging I stop the process so it is never executed, then I have to close the rest of the tabs manually, when I debug tests in Chrome or FF I don't have this problem.